# find the best user in a month of every location

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to find the best user based on location in every month of every year

I am using the following data

```
user_id        location       date                Product_brought
........       .........      .....               ...............
1               ks            2017-08-17             prod1
1               ks            2017-08-17             prod2
2               ks            2017-08-17             prod1
2               ks            2017-01-17             prod5
2               ks            2017-01-17             prod4
1               ks            2017-01-17             prod2 
4               Tg            2017-08-17             prod4 
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod5
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod7
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod4
5               Tg            2017-01-17             prod3
6               Tg            2017-01-17             prod4
6               Tg            2017-01-17             prod3 
6               Tg            2017-08-17             prod1 
1               ks            2017-08-17             prod1
1               ks            2017-08-17             prod2
2               ks            2017-08-17             prod1
2               ks            2017-01-17             prod5
2               ks            2017-01-17             prod4
1               ks            2017-01-17             prod2 
4               Tg            2017-08-17             prod4 
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod5
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod7
5               Tg            2017-08-17             prod4
5               Tg            2017-01-17             prod3
6               Tg            2017-01-17             prod4
6               Tg            2017-01-17             prod3 
6               Tg            2017-08-17             prod1
```

I am expecting the following output

```
user         year             month        location         count
.....        ....             ......       .........        ......
1            2017                8             ks              2
2            2017                1             ks              2
5            2017                8             Tg              3
6            2017                1             Tg              2 
1            2016                8             ks              2
2            2016                1             ks              2
5            2016                8             Tg              3
6            2016                1             Tg              2
```

I have tried using the following query

```
SELECT ds.*
FROM (SELECT user,month(date),year(date), location, count(product_brought) as c,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(date),year(date) ORDER BY COUNT(product) DESC) as seqnum
     FROM table
     GROUP BY month(date), year(date),location, user
    ) ds
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY c DESC ;
```

It wasn't getting the expected output

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff best is defined by highest count of products brought

Comment: To find an answer, will be helpful if you can show the output you are getting, although not the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 with cte as (
 select
    user_id
   ,year(date) 'year'
   ,month(date) 'month'
   ,location
   ,count(Product_brought) 'count'
   ,row_number() over (partition by user_id, year(date), month(date), location order by count(Product_brought) desc) 'seqnum'
 from TempTable
 group by
    user_id
   ,year(date)
   ,month(date)
   ,location
 )
 select *
 from cte
 where seqnum = 1
```